# The meaning of "into whose orbit had now projected itself......"

Tags: meaning

> My umbrella pursued its career, undecidedly but continuously. Then one
>   of the little juggernauts—if that be the word—began to weep. The other
>   followed. . . . And then? Then, Monsieur, that Falloux—that practical
>   and logical atheist, who believes reason is the source of all leapt
>   into the breach, crying: “But they are attached! Stand still, and I
>   will detach you.” But that they would not do. My perambulating mosque
>   of an umbrella resumed command. Its handle, see, tripped and slid over
>   the stone floor like the pointed foot of a danseuse. This, with the
>   natural elasticity of the ribs, furnished all the motifs of the
>   ballet. As Falloux stooped to the rim of its circumference—being
>   short-sighted in all respects—one side elevated itself, and the point
>   of a rib caught him in the beard beneath the chin. It appeared then
>   that he could not disengage. He made several gestures. Then he cried:
>   “But it is I who am also attached! Stand still, you misbegotten little
>   brats, till I detach myself!” And he laboured with his hands in the
>   thickets of his beard like a suicide who has no time to lose. But he
>   remained—he rested there—conforming with yelps of agony to the agonies
>   of the rival circus, **into whose orbit had now projected itself, at
>   their own level, the head of their abominated preceptor, distorted and
>   menacing. . . .**

This is from "Miracle of Saint Jubanus" by Rudyard Kipling.

I can't understand the meaning of the sentence below.
I am glad if someone would kindly teach me or give me some suggestions.

, into whose orbit had now projected itself, at their own level, the head of their abominated preceptor, distorted and menacing. . . .

Answer (score 2):

We could re-order the lines thus:

"...into whose orbit the distorted and menacing head of their abominated preceptor had now projected itself, at their own level."

Maybe that's all you need? If not. . .

Falloux's head (the head of their loathed teacher) had now stuck/protruded/entered into their orbit (their area of activity; their proximity). His head was at their own level because he was stooping down. And his head was *distorted* because his beard was being pulled and was hurting him and *menacing* because he was angry and the children *abominated* (loathed) him.

By the way, an orbit is curved - perhaps even circular: like an umbrella! The word can also mean an area of activity or of interest. Kipling was probably happy to suggest both meanings.

This is difficult English, Hiroshi!

Comment: Thank you so much, Old Brixtonian, your kind ansew is so helpful!!